# PHP grab json exchange rate value from API response

Tags: php, json

I am using currencylayer JSON API to get realtime currency conversion value - does anybody know how I could grab both the `"result"` value and the `"quote"` value from the API response below using PHP?

I am new to PHP, and I am wondering if it's possible to store it in a variable.

This is the JSON:

```
{
  "success":true,
  "terms":"https:\/\/currencylayer.com\/terms",
  "privacy":"https:\/\/currencylayer.com\/privacy",
  "query":{
    "from":"CAD",
    "to":"GBP",
    "amount":234
  },
  "info":{
    "timestamp":1432829168,
    "quote":0.524191
  },
  "result":122.660694
}
```

I have played around with `file_get_contents("URL")` but I didnt understand how to get a single value out.

Request URL looks like this:

`https://apilayer.net/api/convert?access_key=...&from=CAD&to=GBP&amount=234`

Thanks for the help!

Comment: it's just json. decode it to a native php array, then access it like you would any OTHER php array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, lets say that json response is in a variable named `$response`, you must use `json_decode` and then do as follows:

```
$decoded = json_decode($response);
$result = $decoded->result;
$quote = $decoded->info->quote;
var_dump($result, $quote);
```

Comment: Glad I could help you out :)

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
$jsonArray = file_get_contents($yourUrl);
$jsonObject = json_decode($jsonArray);
echo $jsonObject->result;
echo $jsonObject->info->quote;
```