# How to access a particular JSON data?

Tags: php, json

```
[["pdf-sample.pdf",["uploads\/28\/pdf-sample.pdf"],{"en":"PDF Sample"},"","28"],["pdf-sample2.pdf",["uploads\/29\/pdf-sample2.pdf"],{"en":"Second PDF sample"},"","29"]]
```

Now I know how to access `uploads\28\pdf-sample.pdf` part - just type `$value[1][0]`, but I need to get the description of that file, which is `PDF Sample` - and how can I access that?

My code thus far:

```
$files = json_decode($p['file']);
foreach ($files as $value) {
   echo $value[1][0].'<br />';
}
```

Comment: `your_array[0][2].en` will give you "PDF Sample". "uploads\28\pdf-sample.pdf" is at `your_array[0][1]` not `[1][0]` as said in your question.

Comment: That looks the PHP, and the answer depends on whether you decoded the json into objects or associative arrays.

Comment: @RafH sadly, that doesn't return anything.

Comment: @RafH the `.` notation you used is for `JS` not `PHP`

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP grab json exchange rate value from API response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30513525/php-grab-json-exchange-rate-value-from-api-response)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are decoding it as an object so to access the `en` value you need to do something like

```
$files = json_decode('[["pdf-sample.pdf",["uploads\/28\/pdf-sample.pdf"],{"en":"PDF Sample"},"","28"],["pdf-sample2.pdf",["uploads\/29\/pdf-sample2.pdf"],{"en":"Second PDF sample"},"","29"]]');

    foreach ($files as $value) {
        echo $value[2]->en.'<br />';
    }
```

Comment: @Xeen the code I provided works ... if this doesn't work with your code you need to provide more code, specifically where you are getting `$p['file']`

Comment: Ah, you're right, my bad :) I had mistyped your code. Thanks!