# PHP - Getting array element from Json

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm working with the JSON here: http://steamcommunity.com/id/mitch8910/inventory/json/730/2/

I'm trying to get the `tags[{"name":""}]` part of it. For example, I would want the 'container', from '"name":"Container"'

This is my code here:

```
    $data = file_get_contents('http://steamcommunity.com/id/mitch8910/inventory/json/730/2/');
    $json = json_decode($data);

            foreach ($json->rgDescriptions as $mydata)
    {
         echo $mydata->tags[1];
    }
```

`tags[]` is an array, though I did `tags[1]`, I don't awlays want the '1'th element because the position of "name" could change in the array for different elements, I just did this to test, but I got an error. I have tried multiple ways with multiple errors, that why I'm not posting all the error code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP grab json exchange rate value from API response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30513525/php-grab-json-exchange-rate-value-from-api-response)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way may be to do an extra loop to grab all the name elements:

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://steamcommunity.com/id/mitch8910/inventory/json/730/2/');

$json = json_decode($data);

foreach ($json->rgDescriptions as $mydata)
{
    foreach($mydata->tags as $tag) {
        echo $tag->name;
    }
}
```

or to get the first name of each tag group:

```
foreach ($json->rgDescriptions as $mydata)
{
    echo $mydata->tags[0]->name;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Though, in each of the tag[] arrays, there are a few groups in curly brackets {} and each group has a "name" element in it. Do you think it would be possible to just get the "name" from the first set of curly brackets?

Comment: `$mydata->tags[0]->name;` will just get the first one, without needing the second loop

Answer (score 1):

I updated the whole answer:

```
$json = json_decode($data, true);
if (isset($json['rgDescriptions']) && is_array($json['rgDescriptions'])){
    foreach ($json['rgDescriptions'] as $array_no => $value) {
        if (isset($json['rgDescriptions'][$array_no]['tags'])){
            echo "{$array_no}::::";
            foreach ($json['rgDescriptions'][$array_no]['tags'] as $k => $value) {
                if (isset($json['rgDescriptions'][$array_no]['tags'][$k]['name'])){
                    echo "{$json['rgDescriptions'][$array_no]['tags'][$k]['name']},";
                }
            }
        echo "<br />";

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does this do? All it seems to do is no longer allow me to go through the elements with my foreach, which I need to do, and I still can't get the "name" element.

Comment: I updated the answer. Now it checks if rgDescriptions is set and is an array. If yes it goes deeper through each contained array, and check if it has [name] tag inside the second row of arrays. If it is, then it prints it.

Comment: Thanks, this did work properly. Though I just need the first 'name' element in the tags array because there were a few for each item. I'm sure you could have done this, John C just gave me an answer on how to do that though.